# Get Holoviews RGB value as label

Tags: python, bokeh, rgb, holoviews

I am trying to show the alpha value of my RGB plot as a label when hovering it.

Meanwhile it only shows the RGBA value.

My code:

```
rgba = hv.RGB(np.dstack([r,g,b,a]), bounds=bounds).opts(tools=['hover'])
```

[image of rgb plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdEJu.png) (don't let yourself confuse that the rgba value is 0, that is actually correct here...)

Comment: There may be an easy way to access the alpha channel value, but if so I don't know it, and I'd try a custom hover as in https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/how-to-create-a-conditional-custom-hover-tool-for-a-holoviews-plot/311/2 .

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar thanks for the info. I can see myself implementing this, but how do I specify the `vdims` in the RGB, because I am just giving them a NxMx4 array of values. They don't come with any name that I could write into the `vdims` parameter. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure; hopefully a Bokeh expert can weigh in!